# How do I avoid a circular dependancy when the base class adds an extended class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, require, circular-dependency

I'm using a class that extends from a container class. Each instance of the class is in itself a container, but the top level container is not an instance of the class.

File 1

```
const Command = require('Command');
class CommandManager {
    constuctor () {
        this.commands = {};
    }
    add (object) {
        const command = new Command(object);
        this.commands[command.name] = command;
    }
    get (string) {
        return this.commands[string];
    }
}
```

File 2

```
const CommandManager = require("CommandManager");
class Command extends CommandManager {
    constructor (object) {
        super();
        //Other-code
    }
    // Class Methods
}
```

In runtime it should look something like this:

```
client.commands = new CommandManager();
client.commands.add(object); // Add function also filters down adding to sub elements
```

Or:

```
const command = client.commands.get(string);
command.add(object);
```

The problem is that at least one of these files ends up with an empty object or undefined from the required class. My attempts at follwing other node cirular dependacy solutions haven't worked (Or I didn't understand them properly).

The aim is to keep the 2 classes in their own files, I know I can solve the issue by using the same file (but this would be an exception in the project?), and I'm not sure how I (or a consumer) would go about requiring it logically since they're in different areas.

So which ways could I go about this, that I'm missing?

Comment: a) use depency injection (passing the `Command` class to the `CommandManager` constructor - "here's how to create the commands that you'll manage") b) make the `require('Command')` lazy by moving it inside the `add` method. The Command.js module can resolve its non-circular dependencies before `add` is called.

Comment: That said, I would have expected the inheritance hierarchy to be the other way round - every command is a `Command` instance, but only some of them are command container.

Comment: @Bergi In this case every command is a container, while some of them might not make use of it, I can't differentiate if they will or not. Other people will make the commands, and the Command instance can't have "maybe properties". You could go through a series of flags and checks "work out" if a particular command needs a container, but that adds processing internally and forces the consumer to use those flags.

Comment: If every command is (or: can act as) a container, I don't see why would have two separate classes in the first place. Additionally, that "top level container": why isn't that a command as well?

Comment: @Bergi The lazy getter seems to have been just what I needed. Could you write it again as an answer so I can mark it as one?
Also I'm not too sure, but is it better to do a "let Command;" "If (!Command) Command = require" or just require the command each time (since modules are cached)?

Comment: This pattern typically uses the caching behaviour of `require`

Comment: @Bergi The top level container is the main command system, it's very much not a command, it has no command properties and should never be callable by any of the commands properties. For it to be a command I would need to "spoof" a command for the top level. The internal containers are "subcommands".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment posted by Bergi:

Making the require lazy in the CommandManager file delays the loading of the module and allows the dependancy to be resolved before it is called.

```js
class CommandManager {
    constuctor () {
        this.commands = {};
    }
    add (object) {
        const Command = require('Command');
        const command = new Command(object);
        this.commands[command.name] = command;
    }
    get (string) {
        return this.commands[string];
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an awesome solution! Thanks Aquellia for the great hint.